# Multithreading possible with Mongo?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Whenever I'm CPU bound (running on SSD), I see Mongo only using one cpu on my machine. I have 8. Is it possible for Mongo to utilize that? Preferably in ruby, if not, I can convert over easily.

Comment: This article should answer your question: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work

Comment: How does Ruby fit in there? Do you want to multi-thread the client-side code?

Comment: Well if Mongo can't, I'm okay doing multi-threaded on client side as a hack.

Comment: See also: [Is MongoDB somehow limited to a single core?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773606/is-mongodb-somehow-limited-to-a-single-core).

Answer (score 0):

With the current javascript engine in MongoDB 2.2 (which is Mozilla's SpiderMonkey), only one thread in the mongod process executes Javascript at a time, so JS operations including map/reduce and aggregations will be locked into a single thread. You can perform concurrent map/reduce by plugging in the hadoop adapter. I/O operations which do not use javascript can run concurrently while obeying certain [locking rules](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work) introduced in v2.2, so parallelism can be achieved in a limited fashion. If you are running mongos ([sharding your data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)) you can achieve somewhat better concurrency but in general in a single mongod process you will be limited to a single thread.

Comment: You mean it does not use multiple threads for a single operation, but if you run ten concurrent queries, they can proceed concurrently, no?

Comment: MongoDB 2.2 and earlier use Mozilla's [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(JavaScript_engine)) JavaScript engine by default. As mentioned, only a single thread will execute JavaScript but operations such as MapReduce do yield to allow [concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work). The server issue you linked refers to an upcoming change to Google's [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) JavaScript engine.

Comment: Note: you can already [build from source with V8](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+with+V8) but this doesn't necessarily guarantee higher performance yet.  Some final fixes and testing are being worked on for the 2.3 development cycle (see [SERVER-2407](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407), after which V8 should become the default JavaScript engine.

Comment: @Stennie thanks for the heads up on SpiderMonkey, I grabbed the V8 link from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work which apparently is out of date. The map/reduce and aggregations threading I referenced from the MapReduce video at M102 at education.10gen.com

Comment: @Snez: the concurrency page is not out of date, but I expect you are  referring to the link from that page to SERVER-4258 which makes reference to V8 multithreading improvements.  There has been ongoing work to integrate V8, and as noted in my earlier comment V8 has been an ["experimental" option](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+with+V8) since the 2.1 development cycle.

Comment: @Stennie amazing, I must try out this build.

Comment: I believe the question was not about the JavaScript engines (Map Reduce, $where, etc)