# Does mongoClient have capability to use multiple cpu cores?

Tags: mongodb

I have two node js servers.

First is **using cluster** and I have defined one shared mongoClient for each worker. For more description, I create a client at the start time of the application and use it each time I need without closing It.

The second is running **not using cluster**. But I tried to create client in the same way.

**My question is:** does the latter client use all cpu cores when first core is overloaded or not? I mean do both of them operate in the same way or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is MongoDB somehow limited to a single core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773606/is-mongodb-somehow-limited-to-a-single-core)

Comment: No, this is not exactly the answer. Node js cluster distributes the precesses over cores in the first server. My question is about the differences between clustered and not clustered servers and their impact on mongoClient operation.