# How to increase MongoDB CPU above 100%

Tags: mongodb

I have a 7 cpu server but Mongo will never go above 100% cpu usage.  I have a vanilla Mongo v3.6.2 single node install on Centos 7.  When I rebuild an index on one of my collections the CPU will spike to 100%.  Users will be locked out from accessing other collections during this time (timeout errors).  I have 6 other CPUs available that are idling.

Are there any configurations preventing Mongo from using additional CPU?  I don't want the rebuilding of an index on one collection to prevent users from accessing a completely different collection.

I have checked `ulimits -a` as the mongod user and it returns unlimited for everything.

Example error when running a simple find query on another collection via Robo3T when building an index.  Normally this query returns immediately:

```
Failed to execute all of the script. The script has reached shell timeout (300 seconds) limit.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407336/mongodb-utilizing-multi-cpu-server-for-a-write-heavy-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are "locked out" because of index building not the CPU "spikes".  Below is a quote from online document [Index Build Operations on a Populated Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/).

> By default, creating an index on a populated collection blocks all
>   other operations on a database. When building an index on a populated
>   collection, the database that holds the collection is unavailable for
>   read or write operations until the index build completes.

Comment: Thanks, it seems odd that other collections in the same database are affected.  I guess this means we should move each collection into its own database.